# Private node modules on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, npm

How do I include my node_modules or specify a npm login / auth token for private npm modules?

It appears that GAE no longer lets the node_modules folder be included at all (see [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/issues/106)) and there doesn't appear to be a hook to allow npm to login or set a token.

Comment: How do you deploy ? With nodejs runtime ?

Comment: I was using the nodejs runtime. I ended up creating a custom docker image that extends the GAE base image which I can control npm install and setting the npm token for private node modules. I'll turn this into an answer tonight if no one has a better answer.

Comment: That is exactly what I would advise you to do :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you include a .npmrc file local to the application you want to deploy, it will get copied into the app source and be used during the npm install. You can have a build step create this file or copy it from your home directory. See [this npm article](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118393368555/deploying-with-npm-private-modules).

The .npmrc file should look like this:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=<token here>
```

The Dockerfile I used looks like so:

```
# Use the base App Engine Docker image, based on debian jessie.
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/base

# Install updates and dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q curl python build-essential git ca-certificates libkrb5-dev && \
    apt-get clean && rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*_*

# Install the latest release of nodejs
RUN mkdir /nodejs && curl https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.2.1/node-v6.2.1-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar xvzf - -C /nodejs --strip-components=1
ENV PATH $PATH:/nodejs/bin

COPY . /app/

WORKDIR /app

# NODE_ENV to production so npm only installs needed dependencies
ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN npm install --unsafe-perm || \
  ((if [ -f npm-debug.log ]; then \
      cat npm-debug.log; \
    fi) && false)

# start
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: I accomplished the same but using the standard `FROM node:8` - it seems that App Engine flexible mode simply needs a docker image and everything will just work.